# Third Party Authentication redirect with angular and spring

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-boot, jwt

I have an angular 4 application running on a s3 bucket. The authentication is handled by a third party for single sign on. If the user is not authenticated, he is redirected to the third party app.

After the user is authenticated, a callback function is called on the spring boot, with a SAML token. The API then decodes and gets the user id, generates a JWT token and redirects to the UI, with the token in the query param.

UI then checks for the query param and stores in the web storage.

The issue i have here, passing the JWT token in the query param. Setting a cookie on the spring is not working, because the response to the  callback function goes to the third party app.

Looking for a better solution.

Comment: I did not get this part: "Setting a cookie on the spring is not working, because the response to the callback function goes to the third party app". When you set and send cookie in the response to the browser, it will send it back with next call to server. Check if you are setting path to "/" in cookie, so that browser will send in all request to server.

Comment: Can the cookie be accessed from the javascript?

Comment: No. If cookie is set to be Http only, it can noe be read.